# Function in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I try to use a function in shiny app.

In ui I only call the function.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  myfunctionvis<- testforjson(mods, corpus, myDfm)
  serVis(myfunctionvis)
)
```

and in server side exist all the code for this function:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

testforjson <- function(mods, corpus, myDfm){     
    # Find required quantities
    phi <- posterior(mods)$terms %>% as.matrix
    theta <- posterior(mods)$topics %>% as.matrix
    # the code continues

    return(json_lda)
  }
}
```

and the error I receive is that it can't find the `testforjson` fuction.

How can I fix the error or include a function in server side and call to see the results in ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to create a `global.R` file in which you can declare variables and functions that can be seen globally in your shiny app.

So you just need to put your `testforjson` function in `global.R`.

Check this page for more details: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: thank you it work but unfortunately the serVis(myfunctionvis) is not openning in the shiny but in browser. Shiny window only prints the numbers. Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Can you share a piece of your data ? Like the first five rows ?